# What's the best way to identify event objects from each other?

Tags: jquery

Lets say many clicks are being fired off when clicking on a button, what's the best way to identify each event object so that I can only take the first event object.... Below is the code I tried but not working because its not taking eventCounter() function... I'm not sure if this will fix my problem but I have tried bind and unbind and not working..

```
   var eventIndex;
   var elementOjb;

   function eventCount(eventIndex)
   {
       if(eventIndex == undefined)
       {
         return eventIndex = 0;
       }else
       {
         return eventIndex++;
       }
   }

   $("#file").on("click",{source: eventCounter()}, function(event)
   {
        eventIndex = event.data.source;
        elementOjb = $(this);

        if(eventIndex === 0)
        {
             // create tree
             return false;
        }
   });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can only take the first event object"?  Do you want the click function to be only ran once even if you click it a bunch of times?  You might be thinking of "debouncing": http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: `{source: eventCounter}` // `eventIndex = event.data.source();`  maybe?

Comment: You can also try `$("#file").one("click", function(){`.  This will unbind the event after the it's triggered.

Comment: @Rocket, I tried your solution and it does not stop multiple clicks from being processed.

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene: Which solution?  The `.one()` function or the "debounce" plugin?

Comment: @Rocket, I tried the one() function solution but not using the debounce plugin

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene: Unless you're re-binding the event somehow (loop maybe?), then `one()` should work.  It unbinds itself after the first time it's triggered.

Comment: @Rocket, the one() does work and unbind but when I click again, nothing works. I main issue it too many clicks are coming through. I only want to capture the first event and ignore the other events.

Comment: My reputation to too low to chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to "debounce" your function, that is to say, run it once even though it was triggered multiple times.

There is a jQuery plugin to help with this: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Add that to your page, then change your code to:

```
$("#file").on("click", $.debounce(500, true, function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // return false doesn't work with debounce
    // create tree
}));
```

This will only call your function once (the first time), no matter how many times it was triggered.  Your function will be ran again only after there is a 500ms pause of no triggers.

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ycpgz/

Comment: Really really thanks @Rocket for understanding the problem and providing a solution. The debounce-plugin fixed it immediately.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D